# Python Mysql error while inserting records after deduping

Tags: python, mysql

Made a Sample script in Python to dedupe records from Mysql and was Trying to insert around 15k records in data into Mysql database : 
The query I am using is :

```
 c2.execute("INSERT INTO dedable_city %s VALUES %s" % (values, lst))
```

Where 'values' in the column names and 'lst' is the records.

This is the error on the console:

```
File "dedupe_main3.py", line 208, in <module>
    c2.execute("INSERT INTO deduped_new_table_city %s VALUES %s" % (values, lst))
/cursors.py", line 205, in execute
    self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
```

/connections.py", line 36, in defaulterrorhandler
        raise errorclass, errorvalue
    _mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (1054, "Unknown column 'None' in 'field list'")

This is the query when i print it:

```
INSERT INTO deduped_new_table_city (col,col,col,col,col,col,col,col,col,col,col) 
VALUES (val, 'val', 'val', 'val', 'val', val , val , 'val', 'val', val, 'val')
```

What am I missing here?Tried searching online but to no avail.

**Edit 1 :** 'Values' contain

```
(cluster_id,uniqueid,id,name,hcode,suame,adress,hphone,zipcode,latitude,longitude,rating,city,country)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have an error, you need brackets, it should be:

```
c2.execute("INSERT INTO dedable_city (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (values, lst))
```

or you need your values variable to be something like this:

```
values="(column1,column2,column3)"
```

and the same applies to your lst values

**EDIT**
You can also try it this way:

```
c2.execute("INSERT INTO deduped_new_table_city %s VALUES %s",values, lst)
```

Comment: What do you have in your values variable??

Comment: error : execute() takes at most 3 arguments (4 given)

Comment: I think you have a problem with your **values** variable. Could you show the real value it contains??